# Add a New column in pyspark Dataframe (alternative of .apply in pandas DF)

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dataframe **df**

```python
id    col1
1       abc
2       bcd
3       lal
4       bac
```

i want to add one more column **flag** in the df such that if id is odd no, flag should be 'odd' , if even 'even'

final output should be

```python
id    col1    flag
1       abc    odd
2       bcd    even
3       lal    odd
4       bac    even
```

I tried:

```python
def myfunc(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        flag = 'EVEN' 
    else:
        flag = 'ODD' 
    return flag

df['new_col'] = df['id'].map(lambda x: myfunc(x))
df['new_col'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

It Gave me error : `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

How do is use .apply ( as i use in pandas dataframe) in pyspark

Answer (score 1):

`pyspark` doesn't provide apply, the alternative is to use `withColumn` function. Use `withColumn` to perform this operation.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    [1,"abc"],
    [2,"bcd"],
    [3,"lal"],
    [4,"bac"]
 ],
 ["id","col1"]
)
df.show()
+---+----+
| id|col1|
+---+----+
|  1| abc|
|  2| bcd|
|  3| lal|
|  4| bac|
+---+----+

df.withColumn(
    "flag", 
     F.when(F.col("id")%2 == 0, F.lit("Even")).otherwise(
        F.lit("odd"))
 ).show()

+---+----+----+
| id|col1|flag|
+---+----+----+
|  1| abc| odd|
|  2| bcd|Even|
|  3| lal| odd|
|  4| bac|Even|
+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Is there a Way to use the function(myfunc) and alternative to .apply?
Because in future i will be dealing with other UDF's not only odd/even

Comment: @Shubham in general it's better to avoid UDFs if possible, because they're slower. However in your case, you can simply do `df = df.withColumn('flag', F.udf(myfunc, StringType())("id"))`. Do a google search for pyspark udf examples to learn more.

Comment: @pault is right. But if you want it by udf, i can provide you an example.

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yes, can you please add the example also in the answer using udf, it will be very useful